# How to parse complex JSON data structure with Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to parse this JSON data structure returned from a URLSession containing resource information for a project. Despite many approaches am not getting to the level I need to access the data.

Specifically I need to obtain the job status for the planner role which is the r: and the status which follows the s: in the JSON.

So I think I need to traverse the all values to find the status for the planner role or is there a way to specify that I'm looking for planner and directly be able to retrieve the status for it?

I'm not sure how to traverse it to get to that levels , one of the interesting but challenging parts of this problem is that there are three values for the resource so I don't think a dictionary key value pair is the right model.

```
{
  "Project": 43,
  "definition": [
    {
      "statusCode": 0,
      "entryID": "123",
      "Initiatives": [],
      "validationCode": "1.0.0"
    },
    {
      "statusCode": 0,
      "workProduct": [
        {
          "task": [
            {
              "desc": "define project scope",
              "hours": 120,
              "week": "1",
              "resources": [
                {
                  "r": "planner",
                  "l": "junior",
                  "s": "open"
                },
                {
                  "r": "architect",
                  "s": "senior",
                  "s": "filled"
                }
              ],
              "managerCode": "1285",
              "teamCode": [
                "413"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "scope": "project design"
        }
      ],
      "entryID": "123",
      "validationCode": "1.0.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried multiple solutions attempting to access it, based upon various SO answers and this [article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37):

I can print the JSON object as a string:

```
let stringData = String(data: projectInformation!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(stringData as Any) //JSONSerialization
```

But am not sure that that would be an optimal way of retrieving the values for it.

Definitely appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be messy.

```
do{
  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]

  if let project = json["Project"] as? Int {
    //do something
  }
  if let definition = json["definition"] as? [DefinitionType] {
    // do something
  }
} catch {
  //error
}
```

or

make an initializer `init(json: [String: Any])`

or

use other 3rd party libraries

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score -1):

Just the beginning, but should get you rolling. I parsed it until `workProduct`:

```
let object = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
let dictionaryItem = object["definition"]![1] as! [String: AnyObject]
let workProductItems = dictionaryItem["workProduct"]
```

This yields something like this:

```
{
    scope = "project design";
    task =     (
                {
            desc = "define project scope";
            hours = 120;
            managerCode = 1285;
            resources =             (
                                {
                    l = junior;
                    r = planner;
                    s = open;
                },
                                {
                    r = architect;
                    s = senior;
                }
            );
            teamCode =             (
                413
            );
            week = 1;
        }
    );
}
)
, "validationCode": 1.0.0]
```

Just continue parsing until you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks - so I keep adding dictionary where I see a [ and an array where I see a { ?   Is it a coincidence that the data inside resources no longer matches the set that is in my code? For example, notice that senior is now with architect and has a code of s instead of l? I think it is a problem with using dictionary -whcih doesn't guarantee order but the key value pairs in the inner most level for resources lost its integrity. Do you see what I mean? Thanks

Comment: [] is an array, {} is a dictionary. And you are right, dictionaries are unordered. I recommend you reading more about NSJsonSerialization and finding more examples on how to use it.